# SSIS Sql Server Configuration to load multiple flat files in multiple directories

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I'm working on an SSIS project to load multiple flat files in multiple directories into a SQL Staging table.

FTP Path      |  File Name  |  Headers  |  Delimiter  
E:\ftp\Gems   |  PD_INV.txt  |    Y      | Pipe  
E:\ftp\Janos  |  pd_invc.txt  |    Y      | Pipe  
E:\ftp\Flk121   |  PDINV.txt  |    Y      | Pipe  
E:\ftp\GVRS   |  pdinvc.txt  |    Y      | Pipe

I've figured out how to add a variable and I'm able to loop through it they're all in the same directory; but I can't seem to understand how to use the SQL Configuration option to load a table will the above information to extract the files from these locations.  Please help...

Comment: what exactly u want to ask .. if you are looking for configuration in sql database (path). and does all file have same schema..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an execute sql task with a result set to an object variable.  Or you can use a data flow task to recordset destination (with object variable).  In both cases your query would be select ftppath, filename, headers, delimiter from controltable.

Then you use a for loop container with ado enumeration to iterate this recordset and set variables from the object variable.  This container will execute once for each record in your control table.

Using ftppath and filename you can use your current looping, inside the newly created for loop container to run for each folder or if you have file names in a table you can just do them one at at time.

Hope this makes sense.  There are many articles easy to find on the web about the techniques I described.

Comment: This is a good walk-though for what you told me to do here... I think I've got it figure out.   https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/ssis/implementing-foreach-looping-logic-in-ssis-/